# Use of "them" as an article, not a pronoun

Tags: idioms, slang, determiners, them-the

I've seen a lot of times the pronoun *them* used like an article. For example, in the title of the Delta Rhythm Boys *Them bones*, or in the first sentence of "Money for nothing":

> Now look at them yo-yo's, that's the way you do it.

I know that it's not "proper English" (i.e., not something you'll use in a serious writing), but I'd like to know when it's commonly used, and why. Is there any difference between using it and using *the*?

Comment: Save them britches!

Comment: Obviously there will be some benighted souls who don't even *realise* that using "them" in this way is non-standard/grammatically incorrect. Most of us know this perfectly well, and many of us deliberately say it sometimes in informal contexts largely for the effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a non-standard
*(although perfectly valid within the context of a valid personal and location based free choice in the subset of English which one chooses to consider valid within one's own frame of reference)*
use of 'those' - I think it's also an American dialect/regional variation

Comment: Them Suth'ners sure do talk funny!

Comment: Of note, _those_ isn't an article. It is a pronoun. "Them" is also used as "them's the breaks, kid" which also points toward _those_. +1

Comment: @MT_Head: Dat'd be *Dem Suth'ners*, I think (though if we had them in the UK they'd probably be *Suvnas*).

Comment: @MrHen: If you want to get really technical, *those* is a demonstrative (while *the* is an article), and it can be used as a determiner or a pronoun — in the case of this question, we'd be comparing the determiner use of *those*.

Comment: I have to say I don't love the characterization of *them* as a "misuse" of another determiner, because it carries the implication that the person does it by accident or because they don't know better.  It's a *nonstandard* use to be sure, and it is something to be avoided if one wishes to use Standard English, but I don't think its use is inappropriate *per se* within those dialects/registers where we see it.

Comment: @Kosmo, Ah thank you. Good points in both comments.

Comment: A famous and cherished example of the non-standard determiner usage in lyrics: _Dem bones, dem bones, dem dryyy bones ...._

Answer (score 3):

In African-American Vernacular English (AAVE) *them* often replaces *those*, or less often, the article *the*. Due to hip-hop culture having developed with heavy African-American influence, rap lyrics are often in AAVE.

Although possibly unrelated, *them* is also used in this way in Appalachian English.

Answer (score 0):

To me it would seem to be a form of vulgar argot of the language, much as the use of y'all is seen to be by many. These phrases certainly won't be adopted into standard English via anything less than overwhelming acceptance. But we understand the meaning of the term they used as an article much as we understand the use of "y'all come back now, y'hear" as a reasonable phrase. We just assume that its non-standard, or, less flatteringly, gutter-speak (apologies to Sting and Dire Straits).

Answer (score 0):

The answers so far attribute this to the Southern US. But I don't think this is an innovation in English grammar that came from there. Part of this is because it is also used in dialectical speech in the UK and Ireland. But the other reason is that it seems early modern English would often use "them" where we would now use "those".

For example, the 1662 Book of Common Prayer has

> As we forgive *them* that trespass against us.

The King James version has, in Genesis 12:3:

> And I will bless *them* that bless thee, and curse him that curseth thee: and in thee shall all families of the earth be blessed.

(note that they also did not write "he who curseth" either, as certain prescriptive grammarians might demand)

Shakespeare's Henry IV part I has Falstaff saying:

> A plague upon such backing! Give me *them* that will face me.

The easiest way to find these examples is to search for "them that" (though it is not foolproof, as it can occur in present-day English in phrases with reported speech, like "Tell them that I am here"). However, I have not been able to find any examples without the "that" yet (e.g. "them apples", "them people", "them bones"). It is possible that the standard English of that era only used "them" as a demonstrative when followed by "that" (maybe someone else who knows the history of English better can answer).

However, the other answers are right on one thing. It is no longer part of *standard* English.

Comment: This isn't the determiner usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Perhaps my argument was too indirect, but I did not want to lengthen an answer that was already too long. These were not intended to be examples of the determiner usage of "them", but rather examples where the existence of the determiner usage has changed what is now "prescriptively" considered correct (for example, the 1928 Book of Common Prayer has "As we forgive *those who* trespass against us" instead of "*them that*" from the 1662 version).

Comment: But the very title is 'Use of “them” as an article, _**not** a pronoun_' [emphasis mine, and 'article' should be 'determiner' of course].