# "Them" as a plural definite article

Tags: definite-articles, dialects, them-the

> *Hey, teachers, leave them kids alone!*

Intuitively "them" here sounds like it works like a plural "the".

**Which varieties of English is this usage found in?** When it occurs, does it encode a semantic difference (sort of a demonstrative, perhaps?), or is it just a drop-in replacement for the usual definite article?

I'm particularly interested in its occurrence (or lack of same) in Southern American dialects. To what extent would (American) listeners classify it as belonging to AAVE?

Comment: Related: [Use of “them” as an article, not a pronoun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30249/use-of-them-as-an-article-not-a-pronoun)

Comment: It's just a different way of saying _those_, which is the plural of _that_. They're demonstratives, which are also determiners, like articles; but they're not articles.

Comment: @RegDwighт: I've seen the earlier question, but it was mainly about the meaning, rather than the dialect distribution.

Comment: @JohnLawler: It sounds wrong to represent the Pink Floyd line as "leave those kids alone" -- it's not a particular subgroup of kids the teachers are asked to leave alone, but all kids in general, isn't it?

Comment: *Those kids* can mean *all kids in general* as does *them kids*. And the substitution of *them* for *those* is dialectical, not 'standard' English. (In the sense of 'standard' being not a dialect/ regionalism).

Comment: This issue has been dealt with in at least one earlier question.

Comment: @Kris: If you could point me to one that actually contains an answer to my question (see the bolded part above), I'd be much obliged.

Comment: I should have, to make my earlier comment complete. But I (we) need to search! Let's see.

Comment: Henning, representing the Pink Floyd line as “Leave _those_ kids alone” isn't wrong at all—it's exactly what it means. Compare the Danish translation: »Lad så _de børn_ være«, not »Lad så _børnene_ være«.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In British English, it's a nonstandard variant of the standard demonstrative determiner *those*.

Comment: I don't think it's any different in American English

Comment: Thanks. I sometimes insert that qualification, but never quite sure when it's necessary.

Comment: *"There's gold in them thar hills"* is a famous American quote with this nonstandard *"them"* (it apparently was not said by the person it's usually attributed to, but it's just as American nonetheless).

Answer (score 0):

It definitely belongs to some English regional dialects, most notably Cockney. But it is not acceptable as 'received English', where 'those' is 'de rigeur'. It is the kind of expression which makes middle-class parents tear their hair out when they hear their children using it.